# Weird behaviour of StackView with a label, image view and button inside it

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview

I've a stack view with label, image view and button inside it. This stack view is configured for vertical axis with distribution and alignment set to fill. The label is not aligning to centre of the view as the button does. Why is this weird behaviour seen and how to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1scs9.jpg)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let flowerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Flowers"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    var flowerImageView: UIImageView! = {
        let flowerImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "flowers"))
        flowerImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        flowerImageView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow - 1, for: .vertical)
        flowerImageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh - 1, for: .vertical)
       return flowerImageView
    }()
    
    var editButton = UIButton.customButton(title: "Edit", color: .blue, fontSize: 25)
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
    }
    
    lazy var stack :UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [flowerLabel,flowerImageView,editButton])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        stack.alignment =  .fill
        stack.distribution = .fill
        return stack
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       view.addSubview(stack)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

private extension UIButton {
    static func customButton(title: String, color: UIColor,
                             fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:
            fontSize)
        return button
    }
}
```

Comment: can you upload your desire output as screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `alignment` of the stack view to `.fill`. This means that the arranged views will fill the entire width of the stack view.

When a button is "stretched" to fit the width, its text is centre-aligned. This is because buttons place their `titleLabel`s in the centre of the button by default.

When a `UILabel` is stretched to fit the width however, where the text will appear in the label depends on the label's `textAlignment`. By default, this is `.natural`, which in a LTR language, means `.left`.

So you should do:

```
label.textAlignment = .center
```

Alternatively, set the stack view's alignment to `.center` so the label doesn't get stretched.

```
stack.alignment =  .center
```

Comment: first code snippet works! Thanks for the explanation.. As for the second one, the image scales down in comparison to the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix of your class & stack.distribution = .fillEqually, other then your code is same, also I have attach screenshot for reference add background color to see stackview inner objects.[image]

yes @sweeper is right I have change label alignment and

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let flowerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Flowers"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .purple
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    var flowerImageView: UIImageView! = {
        let flowerImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "premiumPop"))
        flowerImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        flowerImageView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow - 1, for: .vertical)
        flowerImageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh - 1, for: .vertical)
        flowerImageView.backgroundColor = .blue
       return flowerImageView
    }()
    
    var editButton = UIButton.customButton(title: "Edit", color: .blue, fontSize: 25)
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
    }
    
    lazy var stack :UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [flowerLabel,flowerImageView,editButton])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        stack.alignment =  .fill
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stack
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        stack.backgroundColor = .red
       view.addSubview(stack)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

private extension UIButton {
    static func customButton(title: String, color: UIColor,
                             fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:
            fontSize)
        button.backgroundColor = .brown
        return button
    }
}
```

Comment: colouring the view does give a better picture! Thanks!